# Weighted nonlinear least squares fitting of circles

Tags: algorithms, least-squares

I am working on a local positioning project, but with a such a high degree of error in the measured distance of signals from the beacons, the final location has what appears to be an *amplified* amount of error.

The current implementation is using an ${n \choose 3}$ trilateration where each group of 3 beacons is trilaterated to get an $(x, y)$ pair. Then the final position is found by averaging each $x$ and $y$ from $\{(x, y)\}$.

I feel like better results could be obtained if all $(x, y)$ pairs could be used simultaneously instead of averaging the results of each group of 3. That is why I am looking into *weighted nonlinear least squares fitting of circles*. My research shows this to be a good option.

I am looking to be able to do [exactly this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40660/trilateration-algorithm-for-n-amount-of-points#answer-40678) which uses *Mathematica*'s `NonlinearModelFit` function, but without having to rely on a library to do it. The answer in the link also has a helpful graphic in how a final position should look with the given data.

Not being a math person, I am at a loss on how this algorithm works "under the covers" and am needing to implement it in code in my system. Can anyone provide some pseudo-code of the steps involved? The data I can provide the algorithm is a set of $(x, y, distance)$ tuples where $x$ and $y$ are known points of each beacon and the distance is a measured, yet error-prone proximity from the point.

I am open to other suggestions for algorithms as well.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization)? You can define a cost function which adds up the squared error of distance from each beacon, and find the location that minimizes the cost using Newton's method. That's essentially what `NonlinearModelFit` is doing under the hood.

Comment: Thank you @Rahul, but I am not too familiar. I understand somewhat of the Taylor expansion and how it is used in many approximation situations, but I am still not understanding how it it applied to finding an approximate point determined by _n_ circles. Sorry, interpreting a lot of math notation is not one of my strengths. Thanks though! I am sure you are right based on your upvotes. I will try to understand it more, but a stepwise guide would be very helpful.